# SUSY with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, web, susy-compass

I've developed a couple of static sites using SUSY and have the hang of it. Currently, I have a SUSY site in development that will be brought over to a custom WordPress theme. Is anyone else here developing this way (I'm sure there are) and if so, is there anything that you ran across while converting that was out of the ordinary or that I'd need to keep an eye out for? I'm just trying to minimize the potential speed bumps before I get started. Thanks!

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick thoughts from the bus stop —

I have used susy with a basic Wordpress theme. There is no inherent conflict, but many Wordpress themes have complex CSS structures, and complex inheritance that can easily trick you up.

The #1 way people screw up susy layouts is to add side margins, padding or borders unintentionally.

As long as you avoid this and carefully avoid predefined styles you should be fine.

In addition, some general pointers which are not emphasized in the docs:

- 'gem unpack susy' and study the contents of the gem! Most of the mixins are SUPER easy to read and I'm BAFFLED why some devs do not do this.
- susy mixins should only be applied to a few key layout elements
- add background colors liberally (not borders) to debug the layout

Cheers — Chris Blow

Answer (score 0):

While I've never converted CSS built with Susy from a static site to Wordpress I have built a Wordpress theme with Susy. As I develop locally, it functioned as it normally would with no hiccups. Is there something specific you are worried about?

Comment: I guess my concerns would be how WordPress injects WP specific css such as when dealing with nav menus such as Robin alluded to below. Also, when using featured images, WP injects the physical height and width into the html which could cause a big problem when you're developing a responsive site.

Answer (score 0):

Susy works great with Wordpress, I've done a couple custom themes and it's all been really smooth sailing.

The thing I've had to keep an eye on really is Wordpress:

-her ability to generate DIVs within DIVS within DIVS, for, imho, no good reason,

-and keeping my eyes glued to the Codex so I can stay aware of when I can add my own classes to elements so that my scss stays readable and consistent.

wp_nav_menu() is a good example of both behaviors.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Menus are definitely something that I know are going to trip me up! Another is images - specifically post featured images and thumbnails. How are you handling them may I ask?